# What do ..1 and ..2 stand for in R?

Tags: r, reserved-words

Quote from R language definition:

> Notice that identifiers starting with a period are not by default
>   listed by the ls function and that ‘...’ and ‘..1’, ‘..2’, etc. are
>   special.
>
> The following identifiers have a special meaning and cannot be used
>   for object names  if else repeat while function for in next break TRUE
>   FALSE NULL Inf NaN NA NA_integer_ NA_real_ NA_complex_ NA_character_
>   ... ..1 ..2 etc.

However it does not give any further detail. Could anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are used to positionally extract values from the `...` argument of a function. See example below:

```
myfun <- function(...) {
   list(a = ..1, b = ..2, c = ..3)
}

myfun(1,2,3)
# $a
# [1] 1
# $b
# [1] 2
# $c
# [1] 3

myfun(3,2,1)
# $a
# [1] 3
# $b
# [1] 2
# $c
# [1] 1

myfun(1:5, "hello", letters[1:3])
# $a
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# $b
# [1] "hello"
# $c
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

This use becomes obvious if you try to call one of these from the console:

```
> ..1
Error: ..1 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

Comment: Good answer.  Can't see where this would be useful. +1

Comment: There is an example in `methods:::rbind` .